# POST запрос (отправить правильный ключ)

Tags: c#, winforms, xnet

Имеется сайт с авторизацией: `site.ru/account/login` (пример)

При переходе по данному адресу сразу генерируется некий уникальный ключ (токен), который при нажатии на кнопку `Войти` передается в параметр `Token`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сначала подумал, что нужно просто выдернуть этот токен и потом уже передать в post запрос, но после недолгих мучений, меня осенило — когда post запрос формируется, токен уже новый получается (и я проверял, это действительно так).

Вот код:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://site.ru/account/login");
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";

    request.KeepAlive = true;

    var reqParams = new RequestParams();
    reqParams["Token"] = "сюда передаю полученный ключ";
    reqParams["UserType"] = 2;
    reqParams["UserName"] = "------";
    reqParams["Password"] = "------";
    reqParams["RememberMe"] = false;

    string contents = request.Post("site.ru/account/login", reqParams).ToString();
    textBox1.Text = $"{contents}";
}
```

Вопрос, собственно в этой проблеме и заключается. Как передать действующий токен при post запросе? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `когда post запрос формируется, токен уже новый получается (и я проверял, это действительно так)` POST запрос формируется клиентом. У вас клиент токены генерит? Или вы что имели ввиду?

Comment: @tym32167, я может не так выразился, но когда я в `textbox1` передаю результат запроса, я вижу там что авторизация не прошла и другой токен

Comment: @tym32167, а вообще, да.. так и получается. Я ведь написал что при переходе по `site.ru/account/login` сразу генерируется токен, т.е если посмотреть исходный код страницы, то там можно увидеть этот токен который передастся когда будешь авторизовываться

Comment: А вы запрос успешной авторизации отлавливали? Обычно так скрывают id сессии, не более. Может он с чем то другим еще передается?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, отлавливал. Захожу на сайт, смотрю какой токен сгенерировался, прохожу успешную авторизацию (предварительно открыв вкладку `Network`) и вижу что именно тот токен и передался

Comment: Ну а с ним еще что? Может заголовок какой, может еще какой параметр, мы можем этот запрос увидеть? И да, часто такие токены приходят от куда то из вне (другой запрос, на другой адрес), может у вас так же? Отследите процесс его появления.

Comment: ну вроде логично - токен против подделки формы каждый раз генерируется сервером заново. То есть, каждый раз, когда вы получаете ответ от сервера, вам надо искать в нем токен и передавать обратно следующим запросом, иначе вся форма будет забракована.

Comment: @tym32167, `передавать обратно следующим запросом` - так получается при следующем ответе он опять сгенерируется заново, обратно то я его как отправлю? :)

Comment: Каждый ответ сдержит в себе новый токен. Получили ответ1 - запомнили токен1, отослали токен1, получили новый токен2 - снова запомнили, отослали токен2 - получили новый токен3, запомнили, отослали токен3 и тд

Comment: @tym32167, вчера я подумал, что сегодня со свежей головой осмыслю ваш ответ, но так и не понял. Можете привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Комментарий выше и есть пример. Я не знаю, как по другому вам объяснить. Почитайте [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) и [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620618/how-does-asp-net-validate-anti-forgery-token)